# Enviar valores de consola por REST API

Tags: java, json, postgresql, rest, spring-boot

Tengo un proyecto en Spring Boot que se conecta a Postgresql y envía los valores por [consola](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcDHY.png), lo que busco es poder enviarlo a través de JSON en una consulta REST, pero no sé qué parte cambiar del proyecto. Eso es lo que busco que genere:

```
{ 
    "depositarios": {
        "correo": "correo",
        "nombre": "nombre",
        "numTel": "numTel",
        "pApellido": "pApellido",
        "SApellido": "sAellido"
    }
}
```

Esta es mi *main class*:

```
@SpringBootApplication

@ComponentScan("com.abner.springpostgresql.service.impl, com.abner.springpostgresql.dao.imp")
public class SpringPostgresqlApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context= SpringApplication.run(SpringPostgresqlApplication.class, args);
        depoService depoService =context.getBean(depoService.class);
        depoService.loadAllDepo();
    }
}
```

Solo que al ejecutarlo tomcat me envía un mensaje de error 404. [Aquí está mi proyecto completo](https://github.com/abnercoronado/restpostgresql).

**Actualizo:** Este es mi [console log](https://pastebin.com/GaABXAAw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase principal esta mal configurada. Cuando usas @ComponentScan debes tener cuidado de no dejar afuera cualquier paquete que contenga clases a ser inyectadas. Si Remueves los parametros de @ComponentScan de seguro tu servicio funcionará.

```
 @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan
    public class SpringPostgresqlApplication {
    ...
```

El error es el siguiente:
Estas indicandole a spring que solo busque en los siguientes paquetes:

- com.abner.springpostgresql.service.impl
- com.abner.springpostgresql.dao.imp

Pero el controller esta en el paquete:

- com.abner.springpostgresql.controller

En este link te puede ser de mucha ayuda:

[Structuring your code](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html)

Answer (score 1):

Pero depserviceImpl no es un controlador, es un servicio

Necesitas crear una clase que sea un controlador

```
@RestController
public class DepoController {

@Autowired depoService mydepoService;

    @RequestMapping("enviar")
    public String enviar() {
        mydepoService.loadAllDepo();
        return ....
    }
```

---

Por cierto usa la convención de nombres de java y cambia depoService a DepoService

Comment: Si ya corregí mi pregunta, creé un [controlador](https://pastebin.com/GvYuvJiy) pero al ejecutar la aplicación en el navegador solo recibo un error 404.

Comment: @AbnerCoronado asi como lo tienes que dirgirte a la ruta localhost:8080/tuapp/lista Cuando inicia el spring boot puedes ver en el log si se registro ese controlador, aparte si el puerto es ese y otro

Comment: Cuando inicio la aplicación solo me aparece que inicio tomcat pero no que mapeo "/lista", mi puerto es el correcto, inclusive si accedo a localhost;8080 me sigue mostrando el mismo error.